# Como realizar o seed de uma factory dentro de uma outra classe com PHPUnit/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

Estava estudando o framework [`Laravel`](https://laravel.com/), e fiquei com a seguinte dúvida: há uma forma de realizar o seed de uma `factory` dentro de uma classe comum do projeto?

Seria como chamar o comando `php artisan db:seed --class=TabelaSeeder`, mas dentro de uma classe do projeto, e não no terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu gosto muito do framework Laravel por ter uma [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8) excelente que sempre supriu minhas necessidades. Para o seu caso, existe uma parágrafo (*[Programmatically Executing Commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands)*) que explica como você pode utilizar o Facade `Artisan`.

Um exemplo para executar o `db:seed` em qualquer lugar de seu projeto é o seguinte:

```
public function initialize()
{
    // Rollback em todas as migrações e migrar as tabelas novamente
    Artisan::call('migrate:refresh');

    // Alimentar as tabelas
    Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'TabelaSeeder']);
}
```

Ou você pode passar todo o comando como uma string:

```
Artisan::call('db:seed --class=TabelaSeeder');
```